# Permission denied on include()

Tags: php, linux, chmod, chown

I'm trying to include a **PHP** file found in `/home/user/Framework/Core/file.php`.

I have my apache to run virtual host from the DNS to `/srv/www/`.

Then, `/srv/www/index.php` tries to include `/home/user/Framework/Core/file.php` and I get a permision denied.

I changed permission for `/home/` recursive to **744** so it can read it, I also did `chown -R apache /home/`

how can I solve this?

Comment: try setting it to 755.

Comment: i'll include it as an answer so you can give the checkmark. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your permissions for folders to 755, so that PHP has the authorization to execute the opening of them. Additionally, you should set all actual files to 644, as execute permission is only needed for folders.